# Access Default Widget's Controls in Customizer Pane

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer

I'm trying to access any **default** widget's control in the customizer pane, **not the preview** !
So I've enqueue a **testing.js** file under a **customize_controls_enqueue_scripts** action
`/**
 * Enqueue script for custom customize control.
 */
function custom_customize_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'testing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/testing.js', array( 'jquery', 'customize-controls' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_customize_enqueue' );`

In this testing.js file, if I try to reach a control's container like so
`alert(wp.customize.control('text_widget_color_setting').container.length);`
Everything is okay and the result of alert is 1, so I'm reaching the control by the DOM.

But if I try to reach a **default** widget control's container like so
`alert(wp.customize.control('widget_search-2').container.length);`
I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined**
I understand that I didn't define/create this **default** widget control but WP did, however this control have **id="customize-control-widget_search-2"** ?!

The part that is driving me crazy is that if I try :
`alert(wp.customize.section('sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1').controls().length);`
The DOM can see all the default widget's controls under this sidebar-1 section that is created by WP !

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait until the control is guaranteed to be created. There is a deferred pattern you should use:

```
wp.customize.control('widget_search[2]', function( control ) {
    // ...
    console.info( control.container );
    // ...
});
```

Also, the ID format for widget customizer controls is `widget_search[2]` not `widget_search-2`. Note the difference from the DOM element ID.